# problem to find out the average

Tags: php

i want to make a CGPA information system for an Educational institute. Say, there have 6 text box, i want to find out the average of 1st 5 text box number as i give input, but if i fill the 1st 4 box of them then also want to find out the average of 1st 4 text box input number and the result is shown in 6th text box position in the same form.i am trying it in another php file, but it doesnt work. the code is here

```
<?php
        $q1 = $_GET['q_1'];
        $q2 = $_GET['q_2'];
        $q3 = $_GET['q_3'];
        $q4 = $_GET['q_4'];
        $q5 = $_GET['q_5'];


            $x=array($q1,$q2,$q3,$q4,$q5);
            $num=count($x);


            if($num=4)
            {

            $sum= $q1+$q2+$q3+$q4;
            $num=4;
            $avg=$sum/$num;
            echo "bestof(4):$avg";

            }
            elseif($num=5)
            {

            $sum= $q1+$q2+$q3+$q4+$q5;
            $num=5;
            $avg=$sum/$num;
            echo "bestof(5):$avg";
            }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you're initializing `$x`, it's always going to be size 5.  If Question 5 wasn't filled in, your array `$x` would be `("Answer1", "A2", "A3", "A4", Null)`.

Try using `isset()` to determine what ones are filled in from the `$_GET` array, and then build your array accordingly, for instance:

```
if(!isset($_GET['q_5']){
    $x = array($_GET['q_1'],$_GET['q_2'],$_GET['q_3'],$_GET['q_4']);
}else{
    $x = array($_GET['q_1'],$_GET['q_2'],$_GET['q_3'],$_GET['q_4'],$_GET['q_5']);
}
```

Comment: but it shows an error named "Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\tst\tst2.php on line 20" and " if(!isset($_GET['q_5']){ " is in 20 line....using your idea the code are looks like as follows

Comment: <?php
  $q1 = $_GET['q_1'];
  $q2 = $_GET['q_2'];
  $q3 = $_GET['q_3'];
  $q4 = $_GET['q_4'];
  $q5 = $_GET['q_5'];

   
   if(!isset($_GET['q_5'])
   
   {
      $x = array($_GET['q_1'],$_GET['q_2'],$_GET['q_3'],$_GET['q_4']);
   $num=count($x); 
   
   $sum= $q1+$q2+$q3+$q4;
   $num=4;
   $avg=$sum/$num;
   echo "bestof(4):$avg";
   }
   
   else
   
   {
      $x = array($_GET['q_1'],$_GET['q_2'],$_GET['q_3'],$_GET['q_4'],$_GET['q_5']);
   $num=count($x);
   
   $sum= $q1+$q2+$q3+$q4+$q5;
            $num=5;
            $avg=$sum/$num;
            echo "bestof(5):$avg";
   }
   
?>

Answer (score 2):

```
if($num=4)
```

should really be

```
if($num==4)
```

because you want to test for equality and not assign the value 4 to num

Comment: Just to clarify the difference, "=" is assignment, "==" is the equality comparison

Comment: thanx for your answer varzan,but it doesnt work. Actually the elseif part are working for all time, what ever i entered is it 4 or 5 inputs